# Copy files in depended project reference

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a solution with 2 projects, Project1 and Project2
project1 is referencing Project2
Project2 contains a folder called Content that contains xml files
I want that when I build Project1, the content of Project2 will be copy to the Output directory of Project1, (Without the Content folder)
I tried to achieved it using .targets file but it seems like the tasks in there are not executing.

I know I can add the files manually but I want anyone that referenced Project2 will receive the same behavior.

Will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the two Project1’s xml files as a link in the Project2.
When you build the solution, the files will be copied automatically.

In Visual Studio:

- click on Project2’s target folder,
- then right-click on it and add an existing element,
- then browse the XML files in Project1,
- click on the arrow next to Add button on the bottom right corner,
- choose « Add as a link », and voilà !

Read: https://andrewlock.net/including-linked-files-from-outside-the-project-directory-in-asp-net-core/

You can also achieve this by adding XCOPY command lines in the post-build event dialog box :

Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the replay
The thing is that I don't want to add as link
I want that any project that reference Project2 will get those files automatically
Add as link is what we are doing now and trying to avoid

Comment: Then XCOPY in pre or post-build event might be your solution.

Comment: Well, know that even if the XML file (in Project1) is added as a link in Project2, you can still decide to copy it or not to the Project2's output folder via the Visual Studio's property window when you select the linked XML file (in Project2).